# How to get the measured height in Jetpack Compose View?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a plotterView that plots from bottom-left (0, height) to top Right.

```
@Composable
fun PlotterView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, xPoint: Float, yPoint: Float, heightIndex: Float) {
    val path by remember { mutableStateOf(Path().apply { moveTo(0f, height) }) }
    val penColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground

    Canvas(modifier = modifier) {
        path.lineTo(
            size.width * xPoint,
            size.height * (1 - yPoint/heightIndex)
        )
        drawPath(
            path,
            color = penColor,
            alpha = 1f,
            style = Stroke(2.dp.toPx())
        )
    }
}
```

However, the above will error out because it cannot access `height` outside of `canvas`.

I also cannot put into the content of `canvas` this line `val path by remember { mutableStateOf(Path().apply { moveTo(0f, height) }) }` as it is drawScope that is not composable.

How can I get the `height`, so that I can initialize the `path` with `0f, height` properly?

Comment: Height and width should be in the modifier, as Canvas api states that "you MUST specify the size with modifier"

Answer (score 1):

Use BoxWithConstraints to contain your canvas, the use the maxHeight which the BoxWithConstraintsScope provided.

Comment: No reason to do that. `Canvas` expones the `size` by itself

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti but with the canvas size got 0.0 height.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hacking around with

```
        if (path.isEmpty) {
            path.moveTo(0f, size.height)
        }
```

in the Canvas. The code as below, and it got what I wanted.

```
@Composable
fun PlotterView(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, xPoint: Float, yPoint: Float, heightIndex: Float) {
    val path by remember { mutableStateOf(Path()) }
    val penColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onBackground
    Canvas(modifier) {
        if (path.isEmpty) {
            path.moveTo(0f, size.height)
        }
        path.lineTo(
            size.width * xPoint,
            size.height * (1 - yPoint / heightIndex)
        )
        drawPath(
            path,
            color = penColor,
            alpha = 1f,
            style = Stroke(2.dp.toPx())
        )
    }
}
```

But it looks lame, as I need to hack to get the `height`, and not having it when I set the `path` stateVariable